# Translatable content and HTML tags

Tags: internationalization, symfony, translation, twig

I use Twig and I want to make the following content translatable :

```
{% trans %}
You have actually <span class='messageNumber'>{{messageNumber}} message(s)</span> in your mailbox. 
{% endtrans %}
```

But when this translatable content will be parsed by POEdit and sent to translators, they will see the `<span>` tags and attributes.  What can I do to avoid this ?

I thought about doing this way :

```
{% messageNumberFormatted = "<span class='messageNumber'>"~messageNumber~"message(s)</span>" %}

{% trans %}
You have actually {{messageNumberFormatted}} in your mailbox.
{% endtrans %}
```

But isn't it a bit heavy or even bad practice for the translators ? In that case, they can't even see the word "message".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use transchoice with [explicit interval pluralization](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#explicit-interval-pluralization), like this :

```
{% transchoice message_count %}
   {0}You have {{no messages}} yet|{1}You have {{one message}}|]1,+Inf]You have {{%count% messages}}.
{% endtranschoice %}
```

Then maybe you could use [replace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) to replace `{{` with the opening tag, and `}}` with the closing tag. I don't know whether you can directly chain like this

```
{% transchoice message_count | replace('...') %}
```

Or if you must store in a variable by using [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html#set) first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `trans` twig filer with keys representing your sentences.

```
{{ you.have.actually|trans }} <span class='messageNumber'> {{ messageNumber message|trans }} </span> {{ in.your.mailbox|trans }}
```

Comment: But the problem with this solution is that the translator can't change the order of the words in the sentence. It's particularly important in some langages.